# Localhost shows 404 not found on all ports

Tags: apache, localhost, wamp

I just ran into a nasty issue of receiving 404 errors whenever I visit localhost on Apache 2.4. On my Apache configuration, Apache listens to port 80. Entering `localhost:80` on the browser's address bar doesn't solve the issue. Adding other known, used ports on localhost still didn't solve the problem. Equally visited localhost from the IP address `127.0.0.1` but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

After much frustration, I noticed my VPN software was running, and thus redirecting all requests to `localhost` to the proxy server before serving me the contents. Turning off VPN solved the issue for me.